Is the .icu domain bad for SEO?
I'm looking to purchase a domain with a good name at a low cost, and I noticed that many .icu domains are still available. However, after doing some research, I found that .icu domains have received negative reviews, particularly regarding spam activity.
When I perform a Google search using "site:icu", I don't get any results. But when I use other TLDs like "site:asia", "site:aws" and "site:id", I find many websites. Does this mean that Google is blocking or de-indexing .icu domains, or is there another reason for the lack of .icu domains in search results?

I dont think Google is blocking .icu domains, but their reputation for spam might explain why they are less visible in search results. It seems that fewer legitimate websites use .icu, which could affect indexing. If you are looking for a domain, I suggest a more trusted TLD to avoid potential issues.
